# including 2 decimal places in a sum case statement

Tags: decimal, ads

I am trying to sum a case statement and have the output include 2 decimal places but remove the decimal point. Example: my database has a value of 102.1 I need the output of my statment to give me 10210. I am importing through a system that uses an implied decimal.

When I run this query:

`your text`select round(Sum(credit),2)*-1, acct from argldet where date_='6/15/2023'  group by acct

my output inlcudes 0.00 and 63.00

However, when I run this query:

```
select 'FW' as JournalNo, Acct, 'FundWorks Treasurers Export' as Descr, Date_,
case when Sum(credit)>0 then 
round(Sum(credit),2)*-1
when sum(debit)>0 then round(Sum(credit),2) end as Amt,                                                   
case when sum(credit)>0 then 'C'
when sum(debit)>0 then 'D' end as Type           
from argldet where Acct<>''                                                           
and Date_>='6/15/2023'                             
and Date_<='6/15/2023'                                          
group by Acct,Date_                                  
order by Date_
```

It drops the .00 and I get values of 0 and 63

This query removes the decimal but also removes the zeros in the 2 decimal places which i need:

```
select 'FW' as JournalNo, Acct, 'FundWorks Treasurers 
Export' as Descr, Date_,
case when sum(credit)>0 then 
replace((convert((sum(credit)*-1),sql_char)),'.','')
when sum(debit)>0 then 
replace((convert((sum(debit)),sql_char)),'.','') end as 
Amt,
case when sum(credit)>0 then 'C'
when sum(debit)>0 then 'D' end as Type
from argldet where Acct<>''
and Date_>='6/15/2023'
and Date_<='6/15/2023'                 
group by Acct,Date_                       
order by Date_
```